# Can I use these HP RAM on ASRock B85 PRO4?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

Can I use HP DDR3 1333MHz 8GB ECC Reg (593913-B21) memory with an ASRock B85 PRO4 motherboard?

(in danish, but specs are listed):

http://www.bj-trading.dk/bjshop/default.asp?pv=593913-B21&pn=Hewlett-Packard&gruppe=RAM-DDR3-240Pins&vare=954390

What I could find from HP:

https://h10057.www1.hp.com/ecomcat/hpcatalog/specs/provisioner/99/593913-B21.htm

ASRock B85 PRO4:

http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B85%20Pro4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use HP DDR3 1333MHz 8GB ECC Reg (593913-B21) memory with an ASRock B85 PRO4 motherboard?

Nope

> Supports DDR3/DD3L 1600/1333/1066 non-ECC, un-buffered memory

[Source](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B85%20Pro4/?cat=Specifications)